# Remove everything except something in one directory

Tags: macos

```
rm -rf ~/.jenkins/jobs/getfromgit/workspace/gitcheckoutdir
```

remove everything under the directory

```
~/.jenkins/jobs/getfromgit/workspace/gitcheckoutdir
```

How do I remove everything under the directory:

```
~/.jenkins/jobs/getfromgit/workspace/
```

except everything the directory:

```
~/.jenkins/jobs/getfromgit/workspace/gitcheckoutdir
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is first to move the gitcheckoutdir (1), remove the content of workspace (2) and then moving back gitcheckoutdir (3); it'll give:

(1)

```
$ mv ~/.jenkins/jobs/getfromgit/workspace/gitcheckoutdir ~/.jenkins/
```

(2)

```
$ rm -rf ~/.jenkins/jobs/getfromgit/workspace/*
```

(3)

```
$ mv ~/.jenkins/gitcheckoutdir ~/.jenkins/jobs/getfromgit/workspace/
```